# Converting head program to tail C

Tags: c, unix, tail, unix-head

I just got a semi function head program running and I need help making it into a tail program where it will display x number of lines at the end of the file. Here is my head code.
I'm having trouble thinking of how to get the counter to read the entire file then start at the bottom and show the last lines of the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 1024


int numLines = 0;
int linecount = 0;
FILE *src = NULL;
char ch[MAX];


void GetArgs (int argc, char **argv){
if(argc != 4 || argc != 2) {
    printf("Error not enough arguments to continue \n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);

}// end if argc doenst = 4 or 2

if(argc == 2){
    src = fopen( argv[1], "r:");
    numLines=10;

}// end argc = 2

if(argc == 4){
    if (strcmp (argv[1], "-n") !=0 ){
        numLines = atoi (argv[2]);
        src = fopen (argv[3], "r");
        if ( src == NULL){
            fputs ( "Can't open input file." , stdout);
            exit (-1);
        }
        while (NULL != fgets(ch, MAX, src)){
            linecount++;
            fputs(ch, stdout);
            if (linecount == numLines){
                break;
            }
        }

    }//end of nested if
     else if (strcmp (argv[2], "-n") !=0 ){
        numLines = atoi (argv[3]);
        src = fopen (argv[1], "r");
        if ( src == NULL){
            fputs ( "Can't open input file." , stdout);
            exit (-1);
        }
        while (NULL != fgets(ch,MAX, src)){
            linecount++;
            fputs(ch, stdout);
            if (linecount == numLines){
                break;
            }
        }            


    }//end of else
}//end if argc == 4

}// end GetArgs


int main(int argc, char **argv){



GetArgs(argc, argv);

   fclose( src );
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? How would you do it on paper with text? Did you consider reading the file backwards? Etc, etc...

Comment: tail is a little more complex, but for a simple implementation you just need to keep the last N lines in memory as you read through the file and then output these N lines when you hit EOF. Hint: use a circular buffer.

Comment: I wanted to read the entire file get the number then print out lines in a loop. ex. while (numLines > 0){ fileMaxlines - numLines(user input)
numlines-- }

Comment: You might want to give `getopt` a look, may make your programs a bit simpler when you start getting more input options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your variables and style. If I understand, you want to printout last [X] lines from file. [X] - parameter from CLI

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1024

    FILE *src = NULL;
    FILE *src_end = NULL;
    int linecount = 0;
    char ch[MAX];

    int main(int arc, char **argv) {
        int i = 0;
        int letter = 0;

        if (arc != 4) {
            puts("Wrong parameters");
            return 1;
        }

        do {
            src = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            if (src == NULL) {
                puts("Can't open input file.");
                break;
            }

            if (0 != strcmp(argv[2], "-n")) {
                puts("Wrong 2nd parametr");
                break;
            }

            sscanf(argv[3], "%u", &linecount);
            printf("Printout last %u lines, from file:%s\n", linecount,
                    argv[1]);

            src = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            if (src == NULL) {
                fputs("Can't open input file.", stdout);
                return 1;
            }

            for (i = 2; linecount; i++) {
                fseek(src, -i, SEEK_END);
                letter = fgetc(src);
                if (letter == 0x0a) { // 0x0a == "\n"
                    fgets(ch, MAX, src);
                    fputs(ch, stdout);
                    linecount--;
                }
            }
        } while (0);

        fclose(src);
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a counter to pass through the whole file and count the total number of lines (Only call fgets to read one line at a time). Suppose N is the total number of lines and n is the number of last lines to be shown on the screen. Then start again at the beginning of the file pass through N - n lines without showing them on the screen (i.e. dont call fputs), after that call fputs for n number of times.